# OpenGL ESを用いた3D表示のプログラムが、 ‘A/libc﹕ Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV)` で落ちる

Tags: android, java, opengl-es

OpenGL ESを用いた3D表示のプログラム課題への助言のお願いです。

今2つの正六面体を描画するプログラム( Zバッファを有効にしていないもの)を Android 端末で表示させる課題を進めています。

教科書としてオライリー・ジャパンの初めての OpenGL ES を用いて行われているのですが、教科書を読んだ末、次のようなプログラムリストにしてみました。ですが実際に動かしてみると起動後、画面に表示されることもなく落ちてしまいます。どのように変更すればよろしいでしょうか？とても勉強不足で正直何しているのかと思われるようなプログラムかとは思いますが何か助言をもらえないでしょうか？

```java
package com.example.rokumen1;

import javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGLConfig;
import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView;
import android.os.Bundle;

import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.ByteOrder;
import java.nio.FloatBuffer;
import android.opengl.GLU;
import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView.Renderer;

import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL11;

public class rokumen1 extends Activity {

// ! 描写対象のView
private GLSurfaceView glSurfaceView = null;

/**
 * Called when the activity is first created.
 */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    glSurfaceView = new GLSurfaceView(this);
    glSurfaceView.setRenderer(new  GLRenderSample1());
    setContentView(glSurfaceView);
}

// ! Activity 休止時の処理
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    glSurfaceView.onPause();
}

// ! Activity復帰時の処理
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    glSurfaceView.onResume();
}

class GLRenderSample1 implements Renderer {
    float aspect=0.0f;
    int vertices=0;
    int indices=0;
    int  indicesLength=0;

    class Object3D {
        public float posX = 0.0f;
        public float posY = 0.0f;
        public float posZ = 0.0f;
        public float rotateY = 0.0f;
        public float scale = 1.0f;

        public float colR = 1.0f;
        public float colG = 1.0f;
        public float colB = 1.0f;
        public float colA = 1.0f;

        public void drawBox(GL10 gl) {
            //! 行列をデフォルト状態へ戻す
            gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
            gl.glLoadIdentity();

            //! 指定行列を生成
            gl.glTranslatef(posX, posY, posZ);
            gl.glRotatef(rotateY, 0, 1, 0);
            gl.glScalef(scale, scale, scale);

            //! 色指定
            gl.glColor4f(colR, colG, colB, colA);

            GL11 gl11 = (GL11) gl;
            //!頂点バッファの関連付け
            gl11.glDrawElements(GL10.GL_TRIANGLES, indicesLength, GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);
        }
    }

    Object3D box0 = new Object3D();
    Object3D box1 = new Object3D();


    // ! サーフェイス作成時の処理
    @Override
    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig eglconfig) {
        //  Toast.makeText(OpenGLSample_1_2.this, "message", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
        aspect = (float) width / (float) height;
        gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);

        //! バッファを生成
        GL11 gl11 = (GL11) gl;
        {
            int[] buffer = new int[2];
            gl11.glGenBuffers(2, buffer, 0);

            vertices = buffer[0];
            indices = buffer[1];
        }
        //! 頂点バッファを作成する
        // ! 頂点転送
        {
            final float one = 1.0f;

            final float[] vertices = new float[]{
                    //! x y z
                    one,one,one, //!< 0 左上手前
                    one,one,-one, //!< 1 左上奥
                    -one,one,one, //!< 2 右上手前
                    -one,one,-one, //!<3 右上奥
                    one,-one,one, //!<4 左下手前
                    one,-one,-one, //!<5 左下奥
                    -one,-one,one, //!<6 右下手前
                    -one,-one,-one, //!<7 右下奥
            };

            FloatBuffer fb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(vertices.length * 4)
                    .order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asFloatBuffer();
            fb.put(vertices);
            fb.position(0);

            gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
            gl11.glBindBuffer(GL11.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, this.vertices);
            gl11.glBufferData(GL11.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, fb.capacity() * 4, fb, GL11.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
            gl11.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);
        }
        // ! インデックスバッファ生成
        {
            final byte[] indices = new byte[]{
                    0,1,2,
                    2,1,3,
                    2,3,6,
                    6,3,7,
                    6,7,4,
                    4,7,5,
                    4,5,0,
                    0,5,1,
                    1,5,3,
                    3,5,7,
                    0,2,4,
                    4,2,6,
            };
            ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(indices.length)
                    .order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
            bb.put(indices);
            indicesLength = bb.capacity();

            bb.position(0);

            gl11.glBindBuffer(GL11.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, this.indices);
            gl11.glBufferData(GL11.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, bb.capacity(), bb, GL11.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
        gl.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f);
        gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        //! カメラ転送
        {
            gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);
            gl.glLoadIdentity();
            GLU.gluPerspective(gl, 45.0f, aspect, 0.01f, 100.0f);
            GLU.gluLookAt(gl, 0, 5.0f, 5.0f, 0, 0, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
        }

        gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);

        {
            box0.posX = -0.5f;
            box0.rotateY += 1.0f;
            box0.colR = 1.0f;
            box0.colG = 0.0f;
            box0.colB = 1.0f;
            box0.drawBox(gl);
        }
        {
            box1.posX = 0.5f;
            box1.rotateY -= 0.5f;
            box1.colR = 0.0f;
            box1.colG = 0.0f;
            box1.colB = 1.0f;

            box1.drawBox(gl);
        }
    }
}
}
```

ちなみにログでは:

```
01-23 04:22:58.775  17459-17459/com.example.rokumen1 D/NvOsDebugPrintf﹕ Opened!
/dev/nvhost-ctrl 42
01-23 04:22:58.779  17459-17459/com.example.rokumen1 D/libEGL﹕ loaded     
/system/lib/egl/libEGL_tegra.so
01-23 04:22:58.799  17459-17459/com.example.rokumen1 D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_tegra.so
01-23 04:22:58.810  17459-17459/com.example.rokumen1 D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_tegra.so
01-23 04:22:58.856  17459-17459/com.example.rokumen1 D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
01-23 04:22:58.898  17459-17473/com.example.rokumen1 A/libc﹕ Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1)
```

となっています。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

頂点バッファは `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` で合っていますが、インデックスバッファは `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` でなく `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER` にバインドしなければなりません。

Comment: すみません具体的にどこをどのようにすればよろしいのでしょうか？
勉強不足ですみません。

Comment: 具体的にお願いしますとコメントしていましたが
言われた部分を探して変更すると実行できました。
ありがとうございました。